# How to parse output of external command in Julia?

Tags: parsing, julia

Let us say that I have an external command called "Busca01.x" which returns three integers separated by tabs, like this:

```
karel@maquina: Busca01.x
192    891   9029
```

So, I can call this from julia and store the result as a string using either
`readall` or `readchomp`. I need the data as an array or tuple, but I seem to not make it work, despite the obvious structure of the data. I think in `readdlm` may be the answer, but I cannot seem to make it work.

My Julia is 3.7.pre 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since **[readall](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/)** returns a *String*, you want something that operates on a *String*, **split** fits the bill.

#### Base.split(string, [chars]; limit=0, keep=true)

> Return an array of substrings by splitting the given string on
>      occurrences of the given character delimiters, which may be
>      specified in any of the formats allowed by "search"'s second
>      argument (i.e. a single character, collection of characters,
>      string, or regular expression). If "chars" is omitted, it
>      defaults to the set of all space characters, and "keep" is taken
>      to be false. The two keyword arguments are optional: they are are a
>      maximum size for the result and a flag determining whether empty
>      fields should be kept in the result.

So given the output of something like

```
julia> x = readall(pipe(`echo "A B C"`,`awk -F ' ' '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3 }'`))
"A\tB\tC\n"
```

the fields are

```
julia> split(x)
3-element Array{SubString{ASCIIString},1}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"
```

or make it into a tuple

```
julia> tuple(split(x)...)
("A","B","C")
```